# "collapes is not triggering in proper way" when i use the button to open a second collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using bootstrap collapse .In the collapse 1 section i have button "save". When the button is clicked the second Collapse should open. The first try is triggering properly after that its opening and closing the collapse in random manner.

Here is the js fiddle "https://jsfiddle.net/raghulramkish/z40wtdva/"

```
$("#collapseOne").collapse('toggle');
$("#collapseTwo").collapse('toggle');
```

If one collapse is already open, then the remaining collapses should all be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use hide on the collapse that are not open

```
 $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
     $(".collapse").not(this).collapse('hide');
  });
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kcz250us/)

Comment: i am trying this for triggering the collapse action through "<button>"